# product flat data reindex not working in magento

Tags: magento

Product flat data not indexing in magento after file and database transfer host server to xampp localhost.

After truncate all catalog_product_flat table from phpmyadmin, database error continue.

Comment: What error you are getting in while reindexing? check your server variable like max execution timeout which mostly causes issues while reindexing.

Comment: I have increase maximum execution time in htaccess file and php ini file also. i have repair database with magento database repair tools but problem not solve so Truncate catalog_product_flat_1, catalog_product_flat_2,catalog_product_flat_3 table from database. i am testing this website localhost xampp 3.2.1 . if u have any solution plz tell

Comment: product flat data shows processing with error - There was a problem with reindexing process. i am not getting product description page error Whoops, our bad...
The page you requested was not found, and we have a fine guess why.
If you typed the URL directly, please make sure the spelling is correct.
If you clicked on a link to get here, the link is outdated.